# Excluding .cache files from SVN Pending Changes

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, ankhsvn

I'm using Visual Studio with AnkhSVN.

On Building a project I see lot of .cache files in pending changes windows.

Any idea how can I exclude those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the .cache files were added to the repo then you will see them in the pending changes window when they change. Delete them from the repo should do the trick.

Or, uncheck the 'show all files' button.

Comment: I will try deleting .cache files.